# Multiple selection options for html and php

Tags: php, html

I'm hoping someone can assist me. I'm trying to allow a multiple selection on a webpage via PHP, but whilst the list is showing, I cannot get the HTML to call the multiple option.

PHP:

```
    <?php $select_features = New_Options::select_form( Property_A::get_property_features( 'id' ), array(
            'id'      => 'property_feature',
            'name'    => 'property_feature[]',
            'multiple' => true,
            'default' => esc_html__( 'Select', 'name-estate-agent' ),
            'echo'   => false,
        ) ); ?>

    <?php if ( ! empty( $select_features ) ) { ?>

        <div class="prop-sub-form__group">
            <label for="property_feature"><?php esc_html_e( 'Features', 'name-estate-agent' ); ?></label>
            <?php echo $select_features; ?>
        </div>

<?php } ?>
```

And the HTML being called:

```
<div class="prop-sub-form__group">
            <label for="property_feature">Features</label>
            <select name="property_feature[]" id="property_feature[]"><option value="">Select</option><option value="38" >Air conditioning</option><option value="62" >Annexe</option><option value="39" >Balcony</option><option value="46" >Concrete Flooring</option><option value="58" >Garden</option><option value="61" >Gym</option><option value="59" >Indoor Pool</option><option value="57" >Off-street Parking</option></select></div>
```

As you can see, the name is getting the [] multi-select feature, but the multiple='multiple' is missing.
I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: What does `select_form()` do? Change/add it there I guess

Comment: There are a few forms, a couple deal with the status of each item, but this form hold the features for it. I've added the mulitple = true event already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<select  name="property_feature[]" multiple="multiple">` 
you can get multi-value from select property

Comment: Hi @RASHED whilst I know that is the simple solution, the HTML isn't directly editable. The HTML is being called via the php script: <?php echo $select_features; ?> because this is a shortcode

Comment: if want multiple value from drop down you need to use ajax or JavaScript  my opinion